# Find and Replace expression needed in Field Calculator ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, field-calculator

Looking for the Field Calculator code (Python preferred) to replace the last numeral values in a field using another field's values for entire attribute table. Please see screen shot here: [image: replace values]

Answer (score 9):

You could create a Python function for the field calculator using the logic below (using the first record as an example:

```
>>> a = "EW 140 Rd MF 71"  # your primary field
>>> b = str(71.6)          # your secondary field
>>> a.replace(a.split(" ")[-1], b)  #replace the last entry in the list
'EW 140 Rd MF 71.6'
```

Or as a def, this might get your further (this example assumes that you are replacing the last entry in string.

```
def replace_item(primary, secondary):
  '''replace a substring in the primary field with that found in the secondary field:
     string field assumed for primary'''
  a = primary.replace(primary.split(" ")[-1], str(secondary))
  return a

if __name__ == "__main__":
  primary = "EW 140 Rd MF 71"
  secondary = 71.6
  print replace_item(primary, secondary)
```

and you can run it in standalone mode for testing as shown

EDIT
For clarification, when one is doing calculations in the field calculator using Python code blocks, the above code, up to and including the "return a" line is all that is needed.  The rest is for running the code as a standlone program in something like Pythonwin.  So that code goes in the code block when you toggle on the "show code block" checkbox.  To use the above function, make the destination field active and specify the function with the input fields in the expression box.  For example:

replace_item(!PRIMARYFLD!, !SECONDARYF!)

would be used assuming the two obviously named fields listed above (ie. PRIMARYFLD and SECONDARYFLD) if they existed in your table.  The help files in ArcGIS also indicate that field names must be enclosed in exclamation marks, !.  More information can be found in the online help for those wishing to use [Python code blocks](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field_examples/005s0000002m000000/) with the field calculator.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dan, please excuse my ignorance and see the screen shot of my attempt to use this and errors here:http://i.imgur.com/TKQLb.jpg

Comment: Dan's field calculator code can't be used as is. You need to check 'Show codeblock'. Substitute your field names for the values he gave. This all has to go in the pre-logic section. Then, in the, 'ET_Name =' section, simply put 'a' (without quotes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sean, I have tried it in pre-logic but still getting errors, i know it is something simple i am missing... please see screenshot here: http://i.imgur.com/tCt6d.jpg

Comment: you need to use the "def" in the second example as the code block

Comment: i am not grasping this... "primary" "secondary" are ET_NAME and ET_STATION?  What about "__name__" and ""__main__""? latest screen shot with errors here: http://i.imgur.com/eIlcb.jpg

Comment: primary would be the field that you are using as you field that contains the input
secondary is the field that contains the sub-string
The __name__ and __main__ aka in the if statement allows you to run a script for testing without having to load up arcmap, replicate your exact situation etc etc...in short it does nothing.  For further information, check the ArcMap help files on how to use code blocks for field calculations.

Comment: i am completely confused now... can you maybe provide a screen shot of how your error-free code looks in Field Calculator, since mine is nothing but errors and i have tried it about 50 different ways.

Comment: i figured solution using VBA as follows:                                                  1. `Replace([ET_Name],"MP","MP                    ")`

FOR FIELD NAMED 'LABEL'
2. `Left([label] ,37)`

FOR FIELD NAMED "LABEL2"


3) `[label2] & " " &[ET_STATION]`

FOR FIELD NAMED 'LABEL2'

Comment: okay, this 5 minute limit to edit posts is ridiculous, i was trying to make that last post intelligible but ran out of time.... this interface could sure be more user-friendly, especially a carriage return function that doesn't COMMIT your post (i forget when typing here that *enter* is the same as *add comment*)... anyway here's link to my solution: [link](http://shorttext.com/rf8l1t4ayyp)

Comment: You can always edit your original question if you want to add further information.