# Removing numeric characters from alphanumeric value in field calculation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a field containing alphanumeric values in the following format:

```
A-AA00
```

Sometimes they are also

```
A-AAA0
```

I need a Python script I can put in the field calculator in ArcMap 10 that will at least remove the numeric characters, and retrain the alphabetical ones and the hyphen. So that, for example, this:

```
A-AA0
```

becomes this:

```
A-AA
```

I also want to replace the numeric chars with numeric chars from another field. [This Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10749/find-and-replace-expression-needed-in-field-calculator-arcgis-10/18701#18701) entry addresses this issue, but the string has a space before the number and this can be used for splitting and indexing... my strings are not so handily constructed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/howto/regex.html). If you put the following in the code block section of the calculator it will return a string that has all digits stripped, no matter were they are:

```py
import re
def strip_digits(s):
    return re.sub("\d+", "", s)
```

This can then be called from the calculate box as:

```py
strip_digits(!column_name!)
```

If you want to replace characters, add another argument to the function for the replacement characters, and put it in place of the empty string.

Answer (score 4):

just use strip

```
s="AAAA-000"
print s.strip("0, 1,2,3,etc")
AAAA-
```

Answer (score 4):

I also found this in the mapping center (arcgis.com).
[resources center text management tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=5DF3F738-1422-2418-34A8-48F478D5FD5B)

It is old code written for 9.2/9.3. 
Not sure about appropriateness for 10.x
The description reads...

> 1. Batch Find and Replace: This tool populates strings in a text field with replacement strings that are specified in a Find/Replace table.
>      This is useful for standardizing label strings or introducing and
>      enforcing standard abbreviations.
> 2. Convert Text to Proper Case: This tool converts the text strings in one field (presumed to be all upper or all lower case) to a proper
>      case (mixed upper and lower case) text string in another (new) field.
>      This tool is written to handle common abbreviations such as NE for
>      northeast, so that it won't come out as Ne.
> 3. Extract Hwy Numbers for Hwy Shield Labels: Adds the numeric portion of a highway name to another text field.
>
> All these tools are written in Python and can be modified to
>   accomplish any specific needs you have.

Answer (score 3):

I would start with this simple case:

```
>>> x = "A-AA00"
>>> print x
A-AA00
>>> print x.replace("0","")
A-AA
>>>
```

From there some of the [codeblock examples for Python from the ArcGIS 10 Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002m000000.htm) should give you a headstart to the total solution.

Comment: I think the problem with this is that there's no easy way to handle non-0 digits. That's why regular expressions are so useful, as om_henners pointed out.