# Python codeblock to remove numeric characters from a column not working

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

I am trying to make use of a codeblock found in this thread:

[Removing numeric characters from alphanumeric value in field calculation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18702/how-to-remove-numeric-characters-from-alphanumeric-value-in-field-calculation)

I put this code into the pre-logic script field of the field calculator:

```
import re 
def strip_digits(s):
    return re.sub("\d+", "", s)
```

And call it in the expression as below with the column in question substituted for column_name:

```
strip_digits(!column_name!)
```

And get the following when running it on a column of data type long:

```
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: strip_digits(171752)<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>:expected string or buffer
```

I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong, any ideas?

Comment: What is the name of the column ?

Comment: Column name is SITE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input and output column should be **text type**. It's expecting a string or buffer and you passed probably integer or double.

Comment: That's it, column type is long interger.  Didn't know that allowed text...an example of the data is '1120 - Mesic Hammock'.